# Share data uri image on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, canvas, share, data-uri

I have HTML canvas which i export into data uri image. Now i want to share this image as easy as possible (without creating FB apps and authentication tokens) on Facebook time line by clicking on custom link on my page.

I have tried something like this:

Image generation:

```
var dataUrl = context.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

Sharing link (`onClick`):

```
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(dataUrl)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent('Some text'),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```

When i click the link in Safari I got `Safari cannot open page ... (NSPOSIXErrorDomain:100)`

How can I easily share data uri image via Facebook sharer URL (or some other way)?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: There is no way to share a data url. Either share a real url or upload the image to the users photos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can decode the DataURI to a share-able URL using this nifty service:

http://aminariana.github.io/data-uri-to-img-url/

This service takes a Base64 encoded DataURI via a POST request, and responds with a URL representing the decoded image. It will wrap your image in a page with opengraph META tags in real time.